# Who was the student that previously brewed a potion of sufficient quality to claim the Felix Felicis?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, potions

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* during the potions class Slughorn claimed that the prize of Felix Felicis was won only once before by a student.

> I should point out, however, only once did a student manage to brew a potion of sufficient quality to claim this prize. Nevertheless, good luck to you all.

Who could that student be? What could they have done with the potion?

Comment: Probably Lily or Snape, but not necessarily, could be Riddle as well

Comment: I removed the image because it is of poor quality and I'm not really sure what its relevance is.

Comment: Added the movie tag as this quote doesn't appear in the books.

Comment: Snape without any doubt because Harry used his instructions to brew the potion correctly..

Answer (score 88, accepted):

## Almost certainly Snape

The Harry Potter Wikia has an article for the student aptly named [Unidentified Potions student](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Potions_student). In it, it identifies Tom Riddle, Snape and Lily as possible candidates.

> - This student may have been a member of the Slug Club, as Professor Slughorn accepts talented students.
> - It is possible that this student may have been Tom Riddle, but is more likely it may have been Severus Snape or Lily Evans who were both known to have had an aptitude for Potions.

However, we know that Harry was using the recipes from a book that Snape had written in notes and helpful hints and his own recipes in so it would seem most likely Snape was the prior student. This seems all the more true when we look into how good Snape was at potions.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this quote is mentioned in the books so it would appear to be a film invention.

Comment: What do you think Snape did with the potion?

Comment: @NeoDarwin I don't know. A user on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/7pkj1d/what_did_snape_use_his_felix_felicis_for/) theorises the following: _"I always assumed he took it the night he went to Dumbledore to beg for Lily's life. He was expecting Dumbledore to kill him at sight so he would have tried everything to make sure the message got across."_

Comment: Hmm...I doubt that Dumbledore would kill a 19-20 year old, even if they were a death eater. Does it make more sense if Snape used it to beg the Dark Lord for Lily's life?

Comment: How do you get from a list of candidates on the wiki to 'almost certainly Snape'?

Comment: @TheDarkLord I don't get it from that, I'm simply saying the wikia mentions these three though with this evidence (his book, skill) it's most probably Snape.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Jealous because he didn't choose you in this list? Anyway, I always assumed it was Snape. I don't have any proof (and there doesn't seem to be any), but IIRC Slughorn says that minutes before Harry uses Snape instructions in the textbook to win the prize. For me, the movie imply that the only student who ever won the prize is the HBP, I may be wrong though.

Comment: I think it's unlikely it was Tom Riddle, as Slughorn was clearly guilty about his past association, so it seems to me odd that he'd refer to Tom Riddle casually, even if not by name. I personally would think he'd just not mention anything having to do with Tom Riddle at all if he could help it.

Comment: I thought it was Tom riddle because he could have used it to frame Hagrid but this makes sense.

Comment: Look at what we know: 1. The students were all using the same textbook. 2. Slughorn's class has been using this same textbook for long enough that Snape used it in his time as a student; presumably longer. 3. The textbook's instructions are sufficiently flawed that when following them to the letter, not even Hermione can get the potion right. 4. Snape's amendments to the instructions allow Harry, who only got mediocre Potions marks beforehand, to brew the potion perfectly. Thus, it was almost certainly Snape. Everyone else would have used the textbook's method, which doesn't work.

Comment: Logic leans towards Snape. Slughorn seems to have this contest every year he's teaching potions, when they get to the draught of living death potion in their curriculum. Only one kid ever won, and Snape clearly figured out at some point a winning recipe. It makes more sense if Snape was creating his notes along with or ahead of where he was in class, rather than after these things were covered. So if he were being taught by Slughorn when he got to draught of living death, surely he would have won with the improved instructions he made ahead of time.

Comment: To pile onto other trains of thought: one student has successfully brewed the potion in Slughorn's class before. One book has the proper instructions for brewing the potion. We know Snape wrote those instructions. So, while it's certainly possible any student at all could have used that book (because, lets be honest, if Harry could follow those instructions most students probably could), it's the most likely Snape is our mystery student.

Comment: While I agree that the circumstantial evidence points strongly to Snape, it is still circumstantial evidence. That said, I don't believe there's a canonical source (other than asking JKR) for this, so this is probably the best we're going to get. +1

Comment: I also think Snape is the most likely candidate, based on available information, but it's not a logical-deduction situation. It defies belief that a textbook in print for so long would have objectively incorrect instructions for the draught, and errors which are never addressed by the instructor (Hermione would presumably have incorporated all available information). The textbook seems simply to be poor quality as a plot device without any effect elsewhere in the stories or setting, making any deductions based on it convenient rather than logically sound.

Comment: @Upper_Case it's also thematically appropriate for this to be a reference to Snape in a movie adaptation of the book that bears his name

Comment: @Upper_Case - The recipe isn't incorrect; it's clearly just much harder to get right than Snape's version (but presumably doable by the end of the year for most people who pass the class).

Comment: @Adamant Not to be difficult, but is there evidence for that? As written (as I recall) Hermione followed the instructions *exactly*, and did not succeed (signs of a correctly brewed batch did not appear for her). Though perhaps it still "worked", but was lower quality in some undefined way. And the additions from HBP's textbook included elements which are known to frustrate potion-making (direction of stirs, referenced also in the Polyjuice potion from *Chamber of Secrets*). Apologies, I don't have my copy at the moment so I can't reference this section directly.

Comment: @Upper_Case - Hermione isn't perfect, and Snape made it clear that potion making requires more than just following recipes. It's fairly clear that Slughorn and Snape were teaching students to make the potion: presumably students mastered the *first potion of the semester* by the end of the year.

Comment: @Adamant True enough that Hermione is not perfect, but her schoolwork is held out to be essentially so (there are instances where she is not, explicitly called out in the text. Otherwise she's as reliable as textbooks and professors). Following recipes is apparently most of what's needed, provided that those recipes are correct (see Harry's successes in HBP-- he exactly follows recipes). It's obviously not definitive, as we simply don't have enough information to reach such a conclusion. Your stance certainly *may* be correct, but it fits awkwardly with some of what is explicitly written.

Answer (score 39):

Apparently the movie and book represent alternate realities, because this never happened in the book. However, *if it would have happened in the book*, we can venture a guess that Snape would have been the previous student.

Later in the book (Chapter Fifteen), Slughorn discusses Harry's Potions ability with other teachers, and he mentions the amazing Draught of Living Death that Harry concocted (my emphasis):

> "But I don't think I've ever known such a natural at Potions!" said Slughorn, regarding Harry with a fond, if bloodshot, eye. "Instinctive, you know — like his mother! **I've only ever taught a few with this kind of ability, I can tell you that, Sybill — why even Severus —"** And to Harry's horror, Slughorn threw out an arm and seemed to scoop Snape out of thin air toward them. "Stop skulking and come and join us, Severus!" hiccuped Slughorn happily. "I was just talking about Harry's exceptional potion-making! Some credit must go to you, of course, you taught him for five years!"
>
> Trapped, with Slughorn's arm around his shoulders, Snape looked down his hooked nose at Harry, his black eyes narrowed. "Funny, I never had the impression that I managed to teach Potter anything at all."
>
> "Well, then, it's natural ability!" shouted Slughorn. **"You should have seen what he gave me, first lesson, Draught of Living Death — never had a student produce finer on a first attempt, I don't think even you, Severus —"**

In the first paragraph he implies that Snape was the best at Potions prior to Harry. In the last paragraph he implies that Snape's attempt at the Draught of Living Death was the  next best after Harry's.

If there had truly only been one previous student to brew one sufficiently worthy of the prize it would then stand to reason that this student was Snape.

Of course, this is not ironclad evidence as it is possible that Slughorn used Snape as the example because Snape was there, even if there may have been one or two students that were better than him.

Comment: Your answer brings up interesting points. The book implies that more than one have won the thing before Harry and Snape (perhaps).

Comment: @NeoDarwin Note that in the book it’s just discussing the previous amazing submissions; it never says that there was ever a contest prior to Harry’s year.

Answer (score -2):

It was Tom Riddle. Yes Snape's handbook provides a fool proof way of brewing the potion, but the way the 6th HP movie presents a specific scene makes me rethink that it was Tom. The pineapple sweets. It was the scene where Harry is recalling one of Slughorn's memories in the Pensieve. If we assume Tom has taken liquid luck just prior to the meeting, the scene makes so much sense. The scene begins with Tom asking Slughorn if a certain professor will retire, Tom is probably testing the effects of liquid luck and wanting to get confidential information from Slughorn. Slughorn replies, "well I couldn't tell you even if I knew could I?" Which indicates that providing the effects of liquid luck, to make all of your endeavours succeed as long as possible, Slughorn did in fact not know this information, otherwise he would have shared it. The next line is the killer of this theory really. Professor Slughorn says, "By the way, thank you for the pineapple you are quite right it is my favourite...but how did you know?" to which Tom mysteriously replies "...Intuition." In fact, Tom's use of liquid luck allowed him to correctly identify and purchase Slughorne's favourite sweets, probably in attempts to ease him up to share information about the hocruxes. As we learn later in the movie, he in fact reveals the truth about hocruxes to Tom, thanks to tom's use of liquid luck. What makes this theory especially disturbing is that Slughorn massively regrets this memory, probably because he thinks he helped Tom Riddle achieve power and spread evil and misery in the world when he told him about the hocruxes, not to mention killing one of his favourite students and Harry's mother, Lily. But Slughorn doesn't know that his defences were simply down due to the liquid luck he had awarded his student for properly brewing the potion known as Living Dead. Or perhaps in the back of his mind, he does know liquid luck was used against him and regrets having given it to Tom. Evidence for this could be the way he fantasises about reacting angrily to Tom's request about the hocruxes. Probably how the true encounter would have gone about if not for Tom's use of liquid luck.

Comment: This is certainly an interesting fan-theory but all the evidence points to it being Snape, not least because Harry is only capable of brewing a potion of that quality ***due to Snape's recipe***.

Comment: This is quite a hard read at the moment, could you [edit] in some paragraphs to make it easier.