# How did Severus Snape use Felix Felicis potion?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, potions

Horace Slughorn claimed that only once a student prepared a 'good enough' Draught of Living Death potion, receiving a Felix Felicis probe (before Harry did).

I guess that student was Severus Snape.

Has anyone read about how Snape used it?

Comment: Related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203017/who-was-the-student-that-previously-brewed-a-potion-of-sufficient-quality-to-cla?rq=1

Comment: Snape might have tried to start his relationship with Lily Evans, but I have no proof.